# GetMenuString returns empty string

Tags: c, winapi

I'm trying to read string from menu like this :

```
char* buf;
int retLength = GetMenuString(menu, IDM_BLABLA, buf, 0, 0);
pclog("Buffer= %s, Length=%i\n", buf, retLength);
```

The output is :

```
Buffer= , Length=11
```

WHats wrong with this code, the method returns correct non zero length, but empty string ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fourth argument is supposed to be the size of the buffer.  Try rewriting as

```
char buf[100];

int retLength = GetMenuString(menu, IDM_BLABLA, buf, 100, 0);
pclog("Buffer= %s, Length=%i\n", buf, retLength);
```

By passing in 0 as the size of the buffer `GetMenuString` just returns the length of the string, so it did precisely what you told it to do. :-)

Share and enjoy.

Comment: I need to go to sleep ) this is ridiculous.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647983(v=vs.85).aspx

You need to provide an allocated buffer with the maximum length specified in the max count parameter.  You've indicated to the function that that max count is `0`.

You need to provide a buffer for the text to be copied into.

```
char buff[255];
int retlen = GetMenuString(menu, IDM_BLABLA, buf, 255, 0);
```